# How do I call a diamond facet ink message with PolkadotJS?

Tags: ink, cross-contract-call

[`_fallback`](https://github.com/Brushfam/openbrush-contracts/blob/a255c212debdace8b82f84cb104e84b716ccd6ac/contracts/src/upgradeability/diamond/diamond.rs#L193) method panics with the following error when attempting to execute a delegate call to the diamond facet contract:

```
2023-05-20 16:16:58.992 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker runtime::contracts: Execution finished with debug buffer: panicked at 'could not properly decode storage entry', liquid-staking/contracts/staker_facet_v1/src/lib.rs:9:5
panicked at 'delegate call to Some(Hash([46, 17, 244, 97, 239, 143, 12, 230, 177, 213, 29, 31, 98, 41, 120, 162, 191, 252, 0, 246, 27, 27, 11, 181, 169, 178, 84, 85, 242, 153, 54, 95])) failed due to CalleeTrapped', openbrush-contracts-4c291f7aab99c37d/13e82f3/contracts/src/upgradeability/diamond/diamond.rs:193:35
```

I am executing a [contract query](https://github.com/ok-Alice/liquid-staking/blob/diamond-pattern/scripts/include/contract-operations.ts#L98-L131) with the following [arguments](https://github.com/ok-Alice/liquid-staking/blob/diamond-pattern/scripts/deploy-diamond-and-facets.ts#L253-L261) utilizing PolkadotJS which calls the facet contract ink message [`pausable::paused`](https://github.com/ok-Alice/liquid-staking/blob/diamond-pattern/contracts/staker_facet_v1/src/lib.rs#LL47C21-L47C21).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an issue with delegate call (described in OpenBrush repo):
https://github.com/Brushfam/openbrush-contracts/issues/36

Comment: Do you know of any examples that implement one of these solutions as described in the issue? There are not exactly straight forward.